# What does "it" refer to in "Just because it's mental doesn't mean they're a broken person"?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> *A person with bipolar disorder isn't different in that.  However, in addition to those things, the biggest thing is that they need to not be treated like they're defined by their disease.  Just because **it's** mental doesn't mean they're a broken person, and that needs to be respected.* [(Source)](https://www.quora.com/What-kind-of-a-partner-does-a-bipolar-person-need)

Shouldn't it be ***they're*** instead of ***it's / it is***? I don't know what ***it*** here refers to. But if it refers to those who are suffering then it must be ***they're***, not ***it is***.

Answer (score 5):

In that sentence, "it" refers to "their disease" from the previous sentence. While you can use "mental" as a way to describe someone with psychological issues, it is very informal and rather derogatory. An article advocating for support and respect for people with bipolar disorder certainly would not refer to those people as "mental". The sentence is instead saying their disease is a mental one.